# All textfields show same value React

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have text fields that render by an array of objects. if I submit a value to one input all the inputs show the same value. I need to show only the value submitted to a specific input field.

Code

```
this.state.seatsData.map((element) => (
    <li style={{width:'70%', marginLeft:'25%'}}>
    <TextField id={element.seatTypeId} variant="outlined" type="number" 
    onChange={this.handleChange} value={this.state.counter}
    sx={{width: { sm: 200, md: 400 },"& .MuiInputBase-root": {height: 80}}}
    InputProps={{ style: { fontSize: 40 } , shrink: true, inputProps:{max: `${element.availableCount}`, min: 0}}}/>
    </li>
))}
```

~~function~~

```
   handleChange = (e) => {
        let value = (e.target.value ? parseInt(e.target.value) : 0);
        console.log(value)
        let id = e.target.id
        // console.log(value)
        console.log(id)
        let inputId = document.getElementById(id)
        console.log(inputId)
        inputId.value = value
        this.setState({counter: value});
    }
```

Comment: Why are you setting the value by calling `document.getElementById` but not by state variable? Also there is only one `TextField` in the code you shared. Do you map over something? Can you try to make this reproducible?

Comment: i'm mapping over an array of items. i will updated the code

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it all wrong! you don't need to get input element from document!
Each textfield should have its own property in state. the thing you are doing is setting the value in a state which every textfield is reading its value from.

workaround:

```
this.state.seatsData.map((element) => (
  <li>
    <TextField
      onChange={(e) => this.handleChange(e, element.seatTypeId)}
      value={this.state.counter[element.seatTypeId]}
    />
  </li>
))}
```

```
handleChange = (e, id) => {
  const value = +e.target.value || 0;
  this.setState(s => ({ counter: { ...s.counter, [id]: value } }));
}
```

Comment: can you please suggest a workaround for my problem

Comment: @RyanFonseka yes, I made the changes.

Comment: @RyanFonseka I guess you are new to react. Consider using react hooks. react class components are not suggested anymore. in the end I beg you to decide how you want to style your components and do it all that way. this is not clean at all!

Answer (score 0):

obviously you're using one state for all of the TextField, which means just one value has been set for all inputs!

In order to use change handler for multiple inputs:

1: You need to set specific name for each input:

```
<TextField name="firstName"/>
<TextField name="lastName"/>
```

2: you need to create object as a state just like so:

**if you use hooks:**

```
  const [state, setState] = useState({
    firstName: "",
    lastName: ""
  });
```

**if you use class component:**

```
  this.state = {
        firstName: "",
        lastName: ""
      };
```

3: then in your onChange handler function:

```
function handleChange(e) {
  const value = e.target.value;
  setState({
    ...state,
    [e.target.name]: value
  });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First you have to create a state like this and add as many object as you want each object represent a input

```
 const [arr, setarr] = useState([
    { val: "" },
    { val: "" },
    { val: "" },
    { val: "" },
  ]);
```

Now create a function that handle the state update

```
const handleValueUpdate = (newValue, index) => {
    // making a copy of array
    const tampArr = [...arr];

    // making a copy of that object from the array
    const tempObj = tampArr[index];

    //updating value
    tempObj.val = newValue;

    //putting back the object in that array 
    tampArr[index] = tempObj;

    //updating the whole state
    setarr(tampArr);
  };
```

simple function to check the state result

```
const handleSaveValue = () => {
    console.log("===>", arr);
  };
```

**How to use in JSX**

```
return (
    <div className="App">
      {arr.map((item, index) => (
        <input
          key={index}
          value={item.val}
          onChange={(e) => handleValueUpdate(e.target.value, index)}
        />
      ))}

      <button onClick={handleSaveValue}>Click</button>
    </div>
  );
```